# issue with TCPFT fonts

Tags: php, tcpdf

Is it possible to have Polish letters in `TCPDF` generated `PDF` => `ążźśćłó`? 
I used font which work in `FPDF` library named `arial_ce`, but with no result:

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('tcpdf/tcpdf/fonts/arial_ce.ttf', 'TrueType', '', 96);

$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 14, '', true);
```

the same result was in using `DejaVuSansCondensed` font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the arial_ce.z, arial_ce.ctg.z and arial_ce.php files from your TCPDF font folder, and then change

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('tcpdf/tcpdf/fonts/arial_ce.ttf', 'TrueType', '', 96);
```

to this:

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('tcpdf/tcpdf/fonts/arial_ce.ttf');
```

(addTTffont doesn't overwrite an already existing font, even if you change parameters, that's why I mentioned deleting the ones already created.)

The defaults work better for this font.  After doing this, I was able to use polish characters in PDFs made by TCPDF.

Edit: Oh, and of course, TCPDF should be using the same character-set that your source string is in.  In my case that would be UTF-8.